# JSON to encrypt vms in loop of ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I have a JSON ARM template which creates multiple vms through a loop, I thought I could add encryptvm at the end of the loop and it would encrypt all the disks.

However it keeps failing with a strange error

The full json is here:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/Lxmb7Y42

I've used both these parameters.

```
, parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1))]",
```

and

```
, parameters('VMNames'))]"
```

but neither seems to work.

All I'm doing essentially is adding the following resource section in:

```
      "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),'UpdateEncryptionSettings)']",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMNames'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'),'/nestedtemplates/encryptVm.json',parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "vmName": {
            "value": "[parameters('VMNames')]"
          },
          "aadClientID": {
            "value": "[parameters('aadClientID')]"
          },
          "aadClientSecret": {
            "value": "[parameters('aadClientSecret')]"
          },
          "keyVaultName": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]"
          },
          "keyVaultResourceGroup": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyVaultResourceGroup')]"
          },
          "useExistingKek": {
            "value": "[parameters('useExistingKek')]"
          },
          "keyEncryptionKeyURL": {
            "value": "[parameters('keyEncryptionKeyURL')]"
          },
          "_artifactsLocation": {
            "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]"
          },
          "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
            "value": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),'recoveryServicesVault')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('recoveryServicesVaultResourceGroup')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('VMNames'))]"
       // "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments/', concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1),'UpdateEncryptionSettings'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "[concat(parameters('recoveryServicesVaultName'), '/', 'Azure', '/', variables('rsvV2vm'), resourceGroup().name, ';', parameters('VMNames'))]",
              "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
              "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/backupProtectionIntent",
              "properties": {
                "friendlyName": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'), copyIndex(1), 'BackupIntent')]",
                "protectionIntentItemType": "AzureResourceItem",
                "policyId": "[resourceId(parameters('recoveryServicesVaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies', parameters('recoveryServicesVaultName'), parameters('recoveryServicesVaultBackupPolicyName'))]",
                "sourceResourceId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('VMNames'))]"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Can't see where I'm going wrong. Maybe I've added it in the wrong place, but checking on JSON validator tools online and everything seems fine.

Comment: @4c74356b41 hi I’ve tried to recreate the error this morning and I couldn’t get it, this morning I got error regarding dynamic parameter not been set, the error last night was to do with vmnaneencryption concat error, at line 0 position 0 .. sorry I should’ve taken a screenshot last night but the frustration got the better of me

Comment: first of all, your line 476 got a typo, `)` is before the `'`, should be vice versa. can you fix that and get back to me with the error you are getting?

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for your help so far, I’ve got to pop out for staff new year lunch and I’ll try it as soon as I get back. Thanks and I’ll get back to you later.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've made the changes you suggested and now getting the error at this link:https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/4Yw1GJd8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this template is due to the fact you are defining your deployment once for each vm, but you are giving each deployment the same name:

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('VMNames'),'UpdateEncryptionSettings')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
```

you need to add `copyIndex()` function to this name

Comment: Hi, I added parameters(‘VMNames’),copyIndex(1) after each vmname, under the name, but got the same error, as mentioned in the original post, is that because I included (1) not ()

Comment: which is the error in the original post? since you didnt exactly specify it

Comment: Sorry I’m not being very clear, the error i get is the same error as in the pastebin link, do I need to add (parameters(‘VMNames’), copyIndex(),’updateencryptionSettings’)]” to the name section?

Comment: yeah, you need to do that. also, i cant really tell you if something else is wrong, it kinda looks fine, but template is really big, and there is no way I can test it since it has like 50 parameters

Comment: also, i dont think its a particularly good idea to have deployments under vm as resources, I'd separate them and create loops

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'm not sure I'm skilled enough to create loops, what I was trying to achieve is when it deploys a vm it encrypts the hdd during deployment, this works on a single vm template. I've added the copyIndex() and I'm now getting a different error, but this i think references the second vm :( the link to error is https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/yuVSVRXq

Comment: yeah, basically you need to do what it says now, you need to explicitly depend on the parent resource. you will get maaany errors along the way :)